# What is about the Groth16's time complexity？

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

The [Groth16](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf) is the zero-knowledge proof scheme,I want know what is the time complexity of Groth16，including generate proof and verify proof.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following tables can be found on page 4 of the paper that you link to. The "Prover computation" and "Verifier computation" columns tell you the time complexity in terms of the numbers of basic operations, exponentiations and pairing computations.

[image: Tables from Groth 16 paper]